# IoError("failed to fill whole buffer") when reading Apache Arrow IPC file in Rust

Tags: rust, apache-arrow

I am trying to read a binary Arrow file into Rust but I am getting an error `IoError("failed to fill whole buffer")`. I am using Arrow 3. I know that could use `ipc::reader::FileReader` but in my application I actually have the data in memory already.

```
use arrow::ipc;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    println!("Length: {}", try_main().unwrap());
}

fn try_main() -> std::io::Result<usize> {
    let data = fs::read("flights-10k.arrow")?;

    println!("Size of the data: {}", data.len());

    let reader = ipc::reader::StreamReader::try_new(&data as &[u8]).unwrap();
    return Ok(reader.schema().fields().len());
}
```

In my cargo file

```
[dependencies]
arrow = "3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Cursor seems to allow me to use the File reader instead.

```
let cursor = Cursor::new(&data as &[u8]);
let reader = ipc::reader::FileReader::try_new(cursor).unwrap();
```